# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with my angular JS function
when I first call this function, everything is good. But my next attempts cause an error and stops it from working.

My js code:

```
     $scope.updateUptimeCalendar = function() {
    $scope.loadHeatMap();
    $scope.getMonthHeatMap(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth());
};

$scope.loadHeatMapData = function (date) {
    var time = date.getTime();
    var isMonthLoaded = false;

    var eps = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6; // epsilont +-6 hours
    angular.forEach($scope.heatMatData, function (record) {
        if (!isMonthLoaded) {
            if (Math.abs(record.date - time) < eps) {
                isMonthLoaded = true;
            }
        }
    });
    if (!isMonthLoaded) {
        $scope.getMonthHeatMap(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth());
    };
};

$scope.getMonthHeatMap = function(fullYear, month) {
    $scope.setLoadingState(true);

    var monthStart = new Date(Date.UTC(fullYear, month, 1));
    var monthEnd;
    if (month == 12) {
        monthEnd = new Date(Date.UTC(fullYear + 1, 1, 1));
    } else {
        monthEnd = new Date(Date.UTC(fullYear, month + 1, 1));
    };

    monthStart = monthStart.getTime();
    monthEnd = monthEnd.getTime();

    var turnOnDuration;
    $http.post('Statistic/GetClientStateStatisticByDays', {
        clientId: $scope.$parent.clientForStatistic.ClientId,
        stateId: 1,
        beginPeriod: monthStart,
        endPeriod: monthEnd
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.$parent.processResponse(data);
        angular.forEach(data, function(record) {
           turnOnDuration = record.Duration / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            $scope.heatMatData.push({
                date: record.AvarageTime,
                value: Number((turnOnDuration).toFixed(0)),
            });
        });
        $scope.heatMatData.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.date - b.date;
        });
        //todo: fixed this when try to get null data values DK
        $scope.setLoadingState(false);
        $scope.cal.update($scope.heatMatData);
    });
};

$scope.heatMapDateParser = function (data) {
    var stats = {};
    for (var d in data) {
        stats[data[d].date / 1000] = data[d].value;
    }
    return stats;
};

$scope.loadHeatMap = function () {
    $('#statistic-modal-chart-container').empty();
    $('#statistic-modal-chart-container-calendar').empty();
    $scope.cal = new CalHeatMap();
    $scope.cal.init({
        data: $scope.heatMatData,
        afterLoadData: $scope.heatMapDateParser,
        considerMissingDataAsZero: true,

        //todo: use to set visible dates interval. MR
        //minDate: new Date(2014, 9),
        //maxDate: new Date(),

        itemSelector: "#statistic-modal-chart-container-calendar",
        domain: "month",
        domainLabelFormat: "%b %Y",
        subDomain: "x_day",
        subDomainTextFormat: "%d",
        itemName: "Hour",
        cellSize: 35,
        range: 1,

        displayLegend: true,
        legend: [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 25],
        legendColors: {
            base: '#ededed',
            empty: '#ededed',
            min: '#FFFFFF',
            max: '#3366FF'
        },
        legendHorizontalPosition: "center",
        previousSelector: "#uptime-calendar-prev",
        nextSelector: "#uptime-calendar-next",
        afterLoadNextDomain: function (date) {
            $scope.loadHeatMapData(date);
        },
        afterLoadPreviousDomain: function (date) {
            $scope.loadHeatMapData(date);
        },

        itemNamespace: "animationDuration-a",
        tooltip: true
    });
};
```

If I use debug, the error occurs in this row $scope.cal.update($scope.heatMatData);

I get this error

my error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at e (http:/Scripts/d3.min.js:3:10447)
at Array.pa.data (http://Scripts/d3.min.js:3:11196)
at Object.CalHeatMap.fill (http://Scripts/cal-heatmap.min.js:8:20667)
at http://Scripts/cal-heatmap.min.js:9:4615
at h (http:/Scripts/cal-heatmap.min.js:9:1605)
at Object.CalHeatMap.getDatas (http:/Scripts/cal-heatmap.min.js:9:1940)
at Object.CalHeatMap.update (http://Scripts/cal-heatmap.min.js:9:4537)
at http://Scripts/Controllers/statistic-ctrl.js:355:24
at http://Scripts/angular.min.js:72:45
at L (http:/Scripts/angular.min.js:99:469) angular.min.js:92
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:92
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:68
L angular.min.js:99
L angular.min.js:99
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:101
k.$eval angular.min.js:111
k.$digest angular.min.js:108
k.$apply angular.min.js:112
h angular.min.js:72
w angular.min.js:77
A.onreadystatechange
```

please anybody help me!

Answer (score -1):

Put

```
$scope.heatMatData = [];
```

as first instruction

Comment: is inserted at the beginning of the file